# using a recursive ajax request with php dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
+----------------------+
| var1 | var2 | output |
+----------------------+
| .... | .... |  ....  |
+----------------------+
| .... | .... |  ....  |
+----------------------+
| .... | .... |  ....  |
+----------------------+
```

I have a table like which consists of two get variables `var1` `var2`.

```
echo'
  <tr>
    <td>'.$array[$num][0].'</td>
    <td>'.$array[$num][1].'</td>
    '.$script.' //bellow
    <td><span class="output"></span></td>
  </tr>
';
```

The rows are created dynamically from an array.

I am wanting the output column to be an ajax function that keeps refreshing.

Something like this:

```
$(function foo() {
    $.get('foo.php', { var1: '".$var1."', var2: '".$var2."'}, function(data) {
        if(data == '0'){
            if (z > 100){
                $('.output:first').html('timeout');
            }else{
                $('.output:first').html('not working');
                setTimeout(function(){foo();}, 10000);
                z++;
            }
        }else{
            $('.output:first').html('working');
        }

    });
});
```

As seen above I am creating this script at the beginning of each row.

But I am having lots of issues where the classes and functions where they must be overwriting each other, is there a better way to do this? And if not how do I prevent all this overwriting.

I have looked into creating a new function for each row but that still leads to overwriting.

Also please bare in mind that there may be more than one of these tables on one page.

Comment: `$('.output:first')` is always the output in the first row, not the row you put the script in.

Comment: Ahh okay! Do you get what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `$var1` and `$var2` in the HTML, and then use a jQuery loop to get all of them and make the AJAX calls for the corresponding row.

I also made the counter a parameter to the function, and increment it when recursing. Your code used a global variable `z` for this, so each row was stepping on the counter of the other rows.

PHP:

```
echo'
  <tr>
    <td>'.$array[$num][0].'</td>
    <td>'.$array[$num][1].'</td>
    <td><span class="output" data-var1="'.$var1.'" data-var2="'.$var2.'"></span></td>
  </tr>
';
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    function update_output(cell, count) {
        $.ajax('foo.php', { var1: cell.data('var1'), var2: cell.data('var2') }, function(data) {
            if (data == '0') {
                if (count > 100) {
                    cell.html('timeout');
                } else {
                    cell.html('not working');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        update_output(cell, count+1);
                    }, 10000);
                }
            } else {
                cell.html('working');
            }
        }
    }
    $('.output').each(function() {
        update_output($(this), 0);
    });
});
```